# ElasticBeanstalk and CodegeIgniter

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, apache2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-7

I'm trying to get a code igniter (PHP) site working on Elasticbeanstalk using apache. When i run it php 5.6(EB stack), everything works fine, but when using Php 7.4, i get the following error:

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here
```

I also tried using .ebextensions to override the **Allowoverrride All** but using that php code is displayed in browser rather executing it.

My EB Stack is :- PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.1.0

Note: When i am running the same code in php 5.6 in elastic beanstalk it's working fine

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 and Amazon Linux 1 are incompatible. Since you are migrating from AL1 to AL2, please have a look at [official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html) on doing this. It may provide some info useful to your issue.

Comment: @Marcin i tried the above steps but no success php code is being shown to browser

Answer (score 0):

7.4 will definitely be supported, and I would assume on release. No release date specified - but not long!